Want to read the HTML markup of a webpage. What am I doing wrong here?
namespace WebReader
{
    public partial class frm_Main : Form
    {
        public frm_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frm_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using var clt= new HttpClient();
            var res = clt.GetAsync("https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt");

            while (true)
            {
                if (res.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    var msg = clt.GetStringAsync("https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt");
                    MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This code is supposed to show the contents of the text file https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt, but it shows a message box with some technical information regarding clt object and nothing else.
What am I doing wrong? I am using Visual Studio 2019.

You aren't awaiting the calls so the objects you are using are just Task<T> and not anything actionable yet

You also only need the httpClient.GetStringAsync() call, the one you do before is redundant

The GetStringAsync() call is also asynchronous and returns a Task<String>. You could do with it something similar to what you did with the return of GetAsync(). Anyway, I would replace the while (true) loop with a call to Task.Wait(). Also, see the ContinueWith() method.

As I said in the comments, the GetStringAsync() call is also asynchronous and returns a Task<String>.
You have several options for synchronizing these tasks with your main program.

The one you used: a while(true) loop checking for IsCompletedSuccessfully. This is not recommended at all, because it eats your resources doing nothing.
Using Task.Wait(). This is a blocking call and what you're looking for. (Edited: it's closer to your original loop without eating resources; but you probably don't want to block your form until the HTTP call ends, which would make your program unresponsive. Look for option 3 or Task.ContinueWith())
Using await as in @Joel's answer (*).

This is your code, using option 1 for GetAsync() (again, not recommended) and option 2 for GetStringAsync().
namespace WebReader
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        static void Main ()
        {
            using var clt= new HttpClient();
            var res = clt.GetAsync("https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt");
            while (true)
            {
                if (res.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    var responseTask = clt.GetStringAsync("https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt");
                    responseTask.Wait();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseTask.Result.ToString());
                    break;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

(*) More technical. Asynchronous functions run in a separate Task (think of it as a separate thread or lightweight process, but several tasks may actually reuse the same thread). When you use await for calling an async function B from a function A, the caller (A) won't execute the instructions following the call until the asynchronous task (and the callee, B) completes; but A will immediately return to its own caller. That is, the caller (A) will also be asynchronous (and that's the reason for the mandatory async keyword). If A is your main() function, it may return to the .NET runtime (the Windows Forms loop, etc), while the asynchronous tasks are still running.
Edited. As been said, using await is easier, provided you can tag your Main() function as async. I don't know if you can do that with your version of Windows Forms (read @Mixin comment), but you can take this console application code (which works) as an example:
namespace WebReader
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main ()
        {
            using var clt = new HttpClient();
            var response = await clt.GetAsync("https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt");
            // You should check response.StatusCode here
            var responseContent = await clt.GetStringAsync("https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent.ToString());
        }
    }
}

As an option, you could write exactly the same code in a separate function, just like this one, and call this function from your actual frm_Main() using Task.Wait(yourAsyncFunction()).

It works, yes. But how to do this efficiently with async and await?

@YoustayIgo Use private async void frm_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

I edited my answer for including an example of the await technique. It's still a console application, but you get the idea.

@MinxinYu-MSFT That works. Thanks for spoon feeding a newbie. Much obliged. Marked this answer as accepted.

You welcome. An additional tip: the var keyword is really handy, but it may be confusing when you're learning, because it hides the actual data types of the variables (and returns and expressions, etc). For instance, GetStringAsync(), when used without await, returns a Task (which is a "ticket" that gives you access to the asynchronous task) . But when used with await, it just returns the String (the final result of the task). The same idea applies to all async functions in this context.

Oversimplifying, but you want to await the results of Async methods:
using var clt= new HttpClient();
var res = await clt.GetAsync("https://daera.net/dmoon/testfile.txt");

Do this, and you won't need the while (true) loop.

OK - but since the frm_Main_Load where this code lives in is not marked with async, then the await won't be possible - no?

That's right. The async keyword "allows the use of await". Anyway, your current problem is not how you synchronize; it's that you're not synchronizing the second task. Check my answer.

This results in the error saying:  CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

@YoustayIgo so do that: mark the method "async"

@JoelCoehoorn How to do that? I am new to C#. I know VB6 and C++, but I am quite a newbie in terms of Visual Studio and C#. Sorry for being so green.
